# Internet explorer y jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

Estoy haciendo un menú de migas de pan y he conseguido hacer que funcione para `Mozilla` y `Chrome` mostrando solo los últimos 3 registros, pero al llegar a `Internet Explorer 11` me dice al depurarlo "No se puede obtener la propiedad 'breadcrumb' de referencia nula o sin definir". He estado mirando información y he visto que `jquery` le da problemas a la gente con `Iexplorer`. He probado poniendo el meta que se comporte como `edge` y el tema de la caché ponerla en false, pero nada funcionó, si se le ocurre alguna idea a alguien se lo agradecería un montón, un saludo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    bindEventToNavigation();
    showBreadCrumb(); //Show the breadcrumb when you arrive on the new page
});
function showBreadCrumb(){
     $("#breadcrumb").html(sessionStorage.breadcrumb);   
}

function bindEventToNavigation(){
    $.each($("#navigation_links > li > a"), function(index, element){
        $(element).click(function(event){
            breadcrumbStateSaver($(this).attr('href'), $(this).text());
            showBreadCrumb();
        });
    });
}

function breadcrumbStateSaver(link, text) {
   if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
      if (sessionStorage.breadcrumb) {
            
   if (sessionStorage.contador) {
        // Se convierte el contador a entero porque por defecto es una cadena
   sessionStorage.contador = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador) + 1;
    
   } else {
   sessionStorage.contador = 1;
   }
  var breadcrumb = sessionStorage.breadcrumb;
  var breadcrumb2 = new String(breadcrumb);
  var posicion = breadcrumb.indexOf(">> ");
   
  
   if (sessionStorage.contador>=3){
   fijo2 = sessionStorage.breadcrumb.substr(posicion+3, breadcrumb2.length)/*+" "+breadcrumb2.substr(posicion, breadcrumb2.length)*/;
   sessionStorage.breadcrumb = fijo2+ "<a href='" +link + "'>" + text + "</a>"+">> "; 
  
   }
   
   else{
   sessionStorage.fijo=breadcrumb2;
   sessionStorage.breadcrumb = breadcrumb + " <a href='" +
   link + "'>" + text + "</a>"+">> ";
       
   }
  
  }
   
        else {
            sessionStorage.breadcrumb = "<a href='" + link + "'>" + text + "</a>"+">> ";
   
        }
}}
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jQuery estás usando? ¿Si pruebas a reemplazar document ready por `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //aquí el código
  });`

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar tan rápido, la versión de jquery que estoy usando es la 1.9.1 para el IExplorer, he probado ahora mismo el addEventListener reemplazándolo y me sigue dando el mismo error en IExplorer, aunque en los demás navegadores funciona perfectamente por si a alguien le sirve el código. El tema es que por narices en mi caso debemos hacerlo funcionar en el IE 11

Comment: Por cierto el error me lo da en la linea 6, en el $("#breadcrumb").html(sessionStorage.breadcrumb);  donde dice que no puede obtener la propiedad "breadcrumb".

Comment: Ok, entonces puede que el problema sea que `sessionStorage` no está habilitado y debes habilitarlo, creo que se hace desde: `Tools>Internet Options>Advanced` y ahí chequear  `Enable DOM storage`. Para confirmar si es eso, comenta la línea y pon un alert en su lugar. Dado que el identificador y lo que quieres guardar se llaman igual, no sabemos si es que no está reconociendo el elemento HTML o si es un problema de `sessionStorage` en sí. Por eso no conviene nunca llamar dos cosas con el mismo nombre, es confuso.

Comment: Si, eso lo había probado también, la verdad que le dí la vuelta a internet durante dia y medio para buscar soluciones y nada.. Si encuentro la solución o me sale otro parecido y que funcione, lo subiré por aquí. Muchísimas gracias A.Cedano, que dios te lo devuelva con que todas las compilaciones te salgan a la primera (que seguramente sean ya casi todas). Un saludo.